# How to implement the saving of night mode in multiple activities?

Tags: java, android

I tried using an Inflater to check whether the Switch responsible for activating and deactivating night mode in my Settings activity is enabled or not. The MainActivity doesn't remember the night mode state after relaunching the app.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Switch night_mode_sw;

    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "nightModePrefs";
    public static final String KEY_ISNIGHTMODE = "isNightMMode";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.getOverflowIcon().setColorFilter(16777215, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings, null);

            sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            night_mode_sw = findViewById(R.id.night_mode);

            checkNightModeActivated();

            view.findViewById(R.id.night_mode);

            night_mode_sw.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                        saveNightModeState(true);
                        recreate();
                    }
                    else {
                        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                        saveNightModeState(false);
                        recreate();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


    private void saveNightModeState(boolean nightMode) {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

            editor.putBoolean(KEY_ISNIGHTMODE, nightMode);

            editor.apply();

    }

    public void checkNightModeActivated() {

            if (sharedpreferences.getBoolean(KEY_ISNIGHTMODE,false)) {
                night_mode_sw.setChecked(true);
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            }
            else{
                night_mode_sw.setChecked(false);
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.settings) {
            Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(myintent);
            return false;
        }

        if (id == R.id.aboutapp) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.setTitle("About this app")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNeutralButton("GOT IT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.cancel();
                        }
                    })

                    .setTitle("About this app")

                    .setMessage("awsd");

            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}
```

Settings.java:

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Switch night_mode_sw;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "nightModePrefs";
    public static final String KEY_ISNIGHTMODE = "isNightMMode";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

            final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.getOverflowIcon().setColorFilter(16777215, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            night_mode_sw = findViewById(R.id.night_mode);

            checkNightModeActivated();

            night_mode_sw.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                        saveNightModeState(true);
                        recreate();
                    }
                    else {
                        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                        saveNightModeState(false);
                        recreate();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private void saveNightModeState(boolean nightMode) {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

        editor.putBoolean(KEY_ISNIGHTMODE, nightMode);

        editor.apply();
        }

        public void checkNightModeActivated() {
            if (sharedpreferences.getBoolean(KEY_ISNIGHTMODE,false)) {
                night_mode_sw.setChecked(true);
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            }
            else{
                night_mode_sw.setChecked(false);
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                }
            }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu1,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.calculator) {
            Intent myintent = new Intent (Settings.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(myintent);
            return false;
        }

        if (id == R.id.aboutapp) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.setTitle("About this app")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNeutralButton("GOT IT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.cancel();
                        }
                    })

                    .setTitle("About this app")

                    .setMessage("awsd");

            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

I'm not sure what the reason for this is.

Comment: Why do you use try-catch in `onCreate` method? Is any error gets thrown? Maybe that is the problem. Try to comment out try-catch block leaving just the code it is wrapping and run the app.

Comment: It doesn't work without the try-catch

Comment: Then you have a problem somewhere. Comment out try-catch block and run the app. Update your question with the stack trace of the error you get.